# openGL (GLFW) - camera movement and view direction vector

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, trigonometry

I'm making a game in openGL using c++ and GLFW libraries.
I made my camera movement function working, here is the code

```
void Player::mouse_callback(double xpos, double ypos) {

    static float lastX = 0.0;
    static float lastY = 0.0;

    GLfloat xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - ypos;
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    GLfloat sensitivity = 0.1;
    xoffset *= sensitivity;
    yoffset *= sensitivity;

    yaw -= xoffset;
    pitch -= yoffset;

    if (pitch > 89.0f)
        pitch = 89.0f;
    if (pitch < -89.0f)
        pitch = -89.0f;

    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    this->viewDirection = glm::normalize(front);

    cout << "ViewDirection: " << viewDirection.x << " " << viewDirection.y << " " << viewDirection.z << endl;
}
```

(there is also some glrotate in another class)

```
glRotatef(this->pov->pitch, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(this->pov->yaw, 0, -1, 0);
```

Now I think that viewDirection is a vector that indicates the direction I'm going.
I tried now to place a marker next to me that stays always in front of me while I am moving the camera, but its positioning is not correct. This is the part of the code from the draw function of the marker class

```
this->setPosition(this->scene->getPov()->getPosition() + this->scene->getPov()->getViewDirection() * 4.0f );
```

(the 4x is to place it at some distance from me)

Do you have a clue of how can I make the mark always to stay in front of me?

Comment: gluLookAt could help you out https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml

Comment: What is this "marker"? Like a cross-hair?

Comment: marker is a square that I want to be always in front of me just for test

Comment: You could render it directly to NDC, skipping camera properties all together, by loading your matrices with identity. The marker is then positioned on display regardless of camera orientation and position. Not sure if that is what you mean though by "in front of me".

Comment: @ScazzoMatto: You do not give enoguh information in your question, so I can only make some guesses: I think your transformation is inverted. You seem to use these two `glRotate` calls to move the camera - but it doesn't do that, it moves the objects, which is equivalent to moving a virtual camera inversely.